# How can I insert a selected file path from a browse button in a GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new with Python GUI creation and I am trying to get the file path of the .csv file from a directory and print it on a text box in a GUI. I am using tkinter library for the GUI and I can't seem to make it work. Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def browseFile1():
  global infile1
  infile1=askopenfilename()
  txt1.insert(0.0, infile1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("CSV Comparison Tool")
Label = tk.Label(root, text="Select CSV files to compare").grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 30)
browseButton1 = tk.Button(root,text="Browse", command=browseFile1).grid(row = 2, column = 30)
txt1 = tk.Text(root, width = 100, height = 1).grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 30)
root.mainloop()
```

The error says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

I tried 1 button first and applying it on the next one it it works. I am using spyder as a tool.

Thanks!

Comment: "can't seem to make it work" is hard to debug. What happens when you run this? Does it print out errors? Then give us the errors, and tell us why you expected something different there. Please read [mcve] in the help.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. It works now. I edited the question and posted the errors I encountered on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is these lines:

```
Label = tk.Label(root, text="Select CSV files to compare").grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 30)
browseButton1 = tk.Button(root,text="Browse", command=browseFile1).grid(row = 2, column = 30)
txt1 = tk.Text(root, width = 100, height = 1).grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 30)
```

The `grid` method on a widget—like most methods that mutate objects in Python—returns `None`. So you're just storing `None` in `Label`, and `browseButton1`, and `txt1`. So when you later try this:

```
txt1.insert(0.0, infile1)
```

That's trying to call `None.insert`, which obviously doesn't work. Tkinter catches the error, prints it out to the terminal, and keeps going as if your function had never been called.

The solution is to just not do that. Instead, do this:

```
Label = tk.Label(root, text="Select CSV files to compare")
Label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 30)
browseButton1 = tk.Button(root,text="Browse", command=browseFile1)
browseButton1.grid(row = 2, column = 30)
txt1 = tk.Text(root, width = 100, height = 1)
txt1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 30)
```

Now, not only does your code work, it even fits in a typical editor window or Stack Overflow page.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I was following some of the tutorials on web. I haven't noticed that the values are 'None".